# Refactor constant expression if statement in template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'd like to refactor the following code:

```
enum Mode { None, Value1, Value2 }
template <Mode mode>
bool func() {
    if (mode == None) {
        helperNone();
        return funcImplNone();
    } else if (mode == Value1) {
        helper1();
        return funcImplValue1();
    } else if (mode == Value2) {
        helper2(); 
        return funcImplValue2();
    }
    return true;
}
```

because the expression

```
mode == None
```

is computed during a compile time. And also can't thhis code lead to a code bloat (code duplication in an executable file)?

I'm thinking of the following refactoring:

```
template<Mode>
bool func() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool func<None>() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool func<Value1>() {
    helper1();
    return funcImplValue2();
}

template<>
bool func<Value2>() {
    helper2();
    return funcImplValue2();
}
```

Is there any other standard way  to refactor that?
Do we have guarantees that compiler will optimize that code itself?
Doesn't the refactored code looks more clear?

Comment: But why? Your optimizer does this for you.

Comment: Do we have any guarantees?

Comment: You might write it like: `if constexpr (mode != None)...`.

Comment: @vahancho I use C++14. So I can't use if constexpr

Comment: @embedc: "*Do we have any guarantees?*" Is this condition being executed in a hot loop somewhere? If not, it's going to be pretty insignificant.

Comment: While there is no guarantee, it would be a poor optimizer that would not optimize this.  I'd rather not have a specialization as they are second class "functions".

Comment: @NicolBolas 1) But is it a good style to combine constexpr expression and a run-time statement ("if") together?  2) Can't it lead to a code bloat?

Comment: @embedc: 1) Just look at the complexity that your code would have to have to avoid it. In the second case, to figure out what `func` does, you have to read *two code blocks* instead of one. Good style is code that is *easier to read*. 2) Why does it matter in light of #1? Any "bloat" would be *at best* trivial, a couple of opcodes. Even if you had 10,000 instantiations of that function (meaning 10,000 enumerators), that's still maybe 40KB of executable size.

Comment: @NicolBolas That refactoring isn't ofcourse very important. But 1) If we have only one such function then there's no significant impact. But what if routinely write the code like that? 2) And what if the function has a lot of if (mode == /*enum value*/) statements?

Comment: @embedc: Both of these are reasons *not* to split the logic up like that. If you have lots of functions like that, having 2x as many functions makes it that much harder to understand what is going on (and to maintain the code). And if you have a function with several such conditions, that means there's a decent amount of code *not* in those conditions, and therefore will have to be *repeated* across the implementations.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've updated the function to make it look more close to the real one. The refactored code looks a little more clear IMHO

Comment: @embedc: If it looks clearer to you, then why are you asking us? You've already decided that splitting up code is more clear to you than putting logic in the same place. This is clearly not about "bloat" to you; it's about personal preference. You seem to be asking us for justifications for what you already prefer.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you! I just wanted to hear other opinions

Answer (score 1):

There is little sense in refactoring here as it is being optimized anyway.
For example following code produces only one call to the funcImpl();

```
enum Mode { None, Other };

bool funcImpl();

template <Mode mode>
bool func() {
    if (mode != None)
        return funcImpl();
    return true;
}

void test()
{
    volatile auto a = func<None>();
    a = func<Other>();
}
```

The result is

```
test():
    sub     rsp, 24
    mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+15], 1
    call    funcImpl()
    mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+15], al
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/V5Uxig

Comment: Do we have any guarantees? Doesn't the refactored code looks more clear?

Comment: No we don't, strictly speaking we don't have them in both cases.  
As for the clarity it is a matter of taste, I'd say that initial implementation with explicit == is more readable.  
But that may depend on the rest of the code base and personal preference.

Comment: What's the problem with the second case? How can it be less optimal that the first case?

Comment: There is no problem, it is ok, but in theory nothing bars compiler from producing code with runtime if. I doubt it may happen in a real life thru. 
If we are speaking about now day compilers both versions are going to the same, when it comes to the performance. But if we speak about guarantees there is basically none.

Comment: Practically speaking it all boils down to the style preference, not performance.